# CSS overlay div does not display correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to display div after clicking button over the content. Button that causes displaying dev is not at the top of the page (you have to scroll down). But overlay div displays wrong, like on the picture. How can I modify the code to display the overlay div always in the middle of the page.

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div id="rating_overlay"></div>
<div id="rating_content">
    <div class="overlay_exit">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()" title="Zavřít">
            <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <h2>Přidat hodnocení</h2>
    <div id="profil_add_rating">
       <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rating_wrapper"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleOverlay() {
        var overlay = document.getElementById('rating_overlay');
        var specialBox = document.getElementById('rating_content');
        overlay.style.opacity = .8;
        if (overlay.style.display == "block") {
            overlay.style.display = "none";
            specialBox.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            specialBox.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 #rating_overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#rating_content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 260px;
    background: #FFF;   
    text-align: left;
}

#rating_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left:24px;
}
```

**EDIT:**
The solution with `position: fixed` works, but I will use http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/.

Comment: I think you're confusing the term overlay with modal.

Comment: You are right. Thank you, I will use this solution http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS' `position: fixed;` is your friend

Position fixed says "put this element in the absolute position according to the window"

CSS for "always on top & center(horizontaly) could be:

```
#rating_wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

**EDIT:** jsfiddle showcase: http://jsfiddle.net/m4Fbk/

CZ: fixni pozice je popsana i na jakpsatwebu ;) http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/position.html

Comment: Díky, pro příště budu vědět ;)

Comment: Jinak vycentrovani absolutne umisteneho elementu at uz fixed nebo absolute je dycky pro verticalni(svisle) `top: 50%; margin-top: -polovinaHeight;` a to stejne pro horizontalni(vodorovne) `left: 50%; margin-left: -polovinaWidth` (marginy maji zaporne hodnoty)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: fixed` for your content div instead of `relative` and correct position with top-left+margin values:

```
#rating_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -130px 0 0 -250px;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 260px;
    ...
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sRrBL/